# Code fails because variable used in if statement is nil

Tags: ruby

I have the following:

```
 def self.parse_categories
    categories = @data.css('#refinements ul').first

    if categories.css('li:nth-child(1) a span').text == "Pet Supplies"
      @categories_hash = {}
      categories_category = categories.css('li:nth-child(2) strong').text
      categories.css('li').drop(2).each do | categories |
        categories_title = categories.css('.refinementLink').text
        categories_count = categories.css('.narrowValue').text[/[\d,]+/].delete(",").to_i
        @categories_hash[:categories] ||= {}
        @categories_hash[:categories][categories_category] ||= {}
        @categories_hash[:categories][categories_category][categories_title] = categories_count
      end 
    else
      @categories_hash = {}
    end

    return @categories_hash
  end
```

Now the code works well in a page which has the element: `#refinements ul` But the code breaks in a page where there isn't. How can I do it so that nothing happens when there is no `#refinements ul`? Like ignoring the code without throwing an error or just skipping to `else`?

Answer (score 1):

Like this, for example

```
def self.parse_categories
  categories = @data.css('#refinements ul').first
  return unless categories

  # carry on
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when `@data.css('#refinements ul')` is `nil`. Right? 
So, try converting it to array and first.
`categories = @data.css('#refinements ul').to_a.first`